# Set attribute to readonly when dropdown value is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this dropdown that has 4 options.

What I want to achieve is to change the attribute of input text `number` to readonly when a user selects `option3` or `option4` from the dropdown.

```
<select id="s_id">
    <option value="option1">option1</option>
    <option value="option2">option2</option>
    <option value="option3">option3</option>
    <option value="option4">option4</option>
</select>

number: <input type="text" name="number">
```

This is the script that I have for now, what it does is just alert the selected value.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#s_id").change(function () {
        var x = $(this).val();
        alert($(this).val());
        if (x == opel) {
            alert("iff");
            $(this).attr("readOnly", "true");
        }
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/mubb413w/)

Any idea/s would be really appreciated!

Comment: can you add code to jsfiddle?

Comment: Give your `input` an `id` and then `$('#input-id').prop('readonly', true);`

Comment: Use, $("input[name='number']").attr('readonly', 'readonly');

Comment: Such fast response guys, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check your `.value` in your `change` handler and use jQuery `.prop` method:

```
$("#s_id").change(function () {
  var isReadonly = (this.value === 'option3' || this.value === 'option4');
  $("input[name='number']").prop('readonly', isReadonly);
});
```

or using an array for making it easier to modify it in future:

```
$("#s_id").change(function () {
  var isReadonly = ['option3', 'option4'].indexOf(this.value) > -1;
  $("input[name='number']").prop('readonly', isReadonly);
});
```

Here is the working **[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ykurmangaliyev/tmp9ss18/)**.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to set the readonly property of the text-box.

1. Create an array of all the values of the drop-down which, when selected, the number text-box should be disabled.
2. Check if the selected value is in the array in the `change` event handler
3. If the selected option value is present in the array, disable the number text-box, else enable it

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/mubb413w/1/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Values when selected, the number box should be disabled
  var values = ['option2', 'option3'];

  // On selection change of the dropdown
  $("#s_id").change(function() {
    // values.indexOf($(this).val()) > -1
    // Checks if the value selected is from the array
    // Comparison returns true when the value is in array, false otherwise
    $('input[name="number"]').prop('readonly', values.indexOf($(this).val()) > -1);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="s_id">
  <option value="option1">option1</option>
  <option value="option2">option2</option>
  <option value="option3">option3</option>
  <option value="option4">option4</option>
</select>

number:
<input type="text" name="number">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `prop` to make `readonly` and remove it back

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/tpxp75hd/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#s_id").change(function () {
    if (this.value === 'option3' || this.value === 'option4')
        $("input[name='number']").prop('readonly', true);
    else
        $("input[name='number']").prop('readonly', false);//enable it back again
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code :-

```
$(this).attr("disabled", true);
```

I think drop down is always read only . what you can do is make it disabled

if you work with a form , the disabled fields does not submit , so use a hidden field to store disabled dropdown value

Answer (score 0):

> Please use this, You can also use it dynamically
>
> Given below the HTML code

```
<select id="s_id">
    <option value="option1">option1</option>
    <option value="option2">option2</option>
    <option value="option3">option3</option>
    <option value="option4">option4</option>
</select>

number: <input type="text" id="number" name="number">
```

> Given below the JQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#s_id").change(function () {
        var option_Array = ["option3","option4"]
        var x = $(this).val();
        $("#number").prop('readonly', false);
        for(var i=0; i<option_Array.length; i++){
           if (x == option_Array[i]){             
             $("#number").prop('readonly', true);
             }
        }       
    });
});
```